# Extract string using regex

Tags: python, regex

How can I extract the content (`how are you`) from the string:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">how are you</string>.
```

Can I use regex for the purpose? if possible whats suitable regex for it.

Note: I dont want to use split function for extract the result. Also can you suggest some links to learn regex for a beginner.

I am using python2.7.2

Comment: Can the string contain any XML escapes such as '&amp;' or even a CDATA section? If so then you should extract the XML-like bit from the start of the string and use an XML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use a regular expression for this ([as Joey demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9031856/78845)).

However if your XML document is any bigger than this one-liner you could not since [XML is not a regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/78845).

### Use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (or [another XML parser](http://lxml.de/)) instead:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> xml_as_str = '<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">how are you</string>. '
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_as_str)
>>> print soup.text
how are you.
```

Or...

```
>>> for string_tag in soup.findAll('string'):
...     print string_tag.text
... 
how are you
```

Comment: Forgive me to correct you here, but a single XML element is definitely regular. XML only becomes non-regular if you introduce element nesting (but the name of the `string` element doesn't really imply arbitrary nesting, so this might be perfectly feasible). Also, isn't BeautifulSoup for parsing malformed HTML? Better to use an actual XML parser, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback: I've updated my wording. This string is not well-formed XML, either (the full-stop at the end).

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">)[^<]+(?=</string>)
```

would match what you want, as a trivial example.

```
(?<=<)[^<]+
```

would, too. It all depends a bit on how your input is formatted exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following regex:

```
/<[^>]*>(.*?)</
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match a generic HTML tag (Replace "string" with the tag you want to match):

```
/<string[^<]*>(.*?)<\/string>/i
```

(i=case insensitive)